# Logging Hashtable Properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a `Hashtable` that I am trying to log the values for.  the name of the `Hashtable` is "props".
My code is as follows:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> keyPairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> items in props)
    {
       keyPairs.Add(items.Key, items.Value);
    }

    Logging.Instance.WriteInformation(string.Format("Key: {0} \t Value: {1}", keyPairs.Keys, keyPairs.Values));
```

However this results in a `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

Is there an easier/more sensible way to log key/value pairs?
Ideally the output would look something like so:

```
 key1        value1
 key2        value2
 key3        value3
```

etc.

As an addition thought, in debugging, the exception seems to occur right at the start of the foreach loop.  I have also tried setting it up as `KeyValuePair<string, object>` but I get the same InvalidCastException.
Would this possibly have something to do with `KeyValuePair` being inside System.Collections.Generic and `Hashtable` being inside System.Collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a loop or, if you want an one-liner:

```
var allPairs = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    keyPairs.Select(kvp => string.Format("Key: {0} \t Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
Logging.Instance.WriteInformation(allPairs);
```

Comment: The LINQ worked pretty well, it turns out the issue was `KeyValuePair<>` inside the foreach loop, once I changed the type it went away and the LINQ helped keep everything concise.  Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just loop:

```
for (var entry : keyPairs)
{
    Logging.Instance.WriteInformation(string.Format("Key: {0} \t Value: {1}", 
                                      entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```

It's only a few lines - you could easily put it in a method if you need it in more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

Log while you are looping.

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyPairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> items in props)
{
   keyPairs.Add(items.Key, items.Value);
   Logging.Instance.WriteInformation(string.Format("Key: {0} \t Value: {1}", items.Key, items.Value));
}
```

Comment: The reason I was originally avoiding this is that the way `Logging.Instance.WriteInformation` works is that it puts a single entry into the file, so I was hoping to keep all the keys/values in one entry

Comment: @wjhguitarman - can you overload WriteInformation() to take a dictionary? Then you can format it internally (using a loop) into a single log entry.

Comment: LINQ it like Tim Schmelter.  :)